# Проверка формата загружаемого файла

Tags: файлы, регулярные-выражения, веб-сервер

У меня на сервер загружается файл с компьютера. Допустимые форматы JPG, PNG, GIF. Необходимо делать проверку на форматы загружаемых фалов. Догадываюсь, что здесь удобно использовать регулярные выражения, однако практически не знаком с ними. Как это проверять? Или существуют более простые способы проверки?

Comment: Имена проверять смысла нет - кто помешает залить что угодно с именем "image.jpeg"? Проверка реального типа файла делается другими средствами, это зависит от вашей платформы и используемого языка.

Comment: Используемый язык php. Про платформу не понял...

Comment: Под linux/bsd, например, есть утилита file. На php можно вызывать getimagesize() и проверять mime в случае успешного завершения.

Comment: Только аккуратней со скриптами: [PHP as JPG][1]


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmNzQRGXb-M

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Во первых я бы установил максимально-допустимый размер файла, ибо картинку можно растянуть и на 40гб. Во вторых я бы отстранился от регулярок и просто проверял бы расширение файла.

```
strtolower(substr($filename, 1+strrpos($filename,".")))
```

Если хочется регулярок, то должно быть примерно так:

```
if(preg_match('!\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$!i', $filename)) {....
```

Comment: ага, а на следующий-же день хостинг бы прикрыли, т.к. с него ломанули пентагон :)

Comment: да неужели?

Answer (score 3):

Вам явно нужно проверять Magic number (подробнее о нём [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)). Регулярка будет не более, чем защитой от дурака.

Answer (score 0):

Вт еще хорошая ссылка которая мне помогла https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list

Обращаю внимание на 1 пункт Disable PHP from running inside the upload folder using .httaccess.
Отключите PHP от запуска внутри папки загрузки с помощью .htaccess.
Вот код:

```
php_flag engine 0
RemoveHandler .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phtml .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .phps .cgi .exe .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .jsp .htm .html .wml
```